# how to select first value in select tag empty(not null) in GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

Here is my domain class `Incident`

```
 class Incident {
      String status
     Usergroup assignmentGroup
     static hasMany={usergroups:Usergroup}
  }
```

I want to find all incidents by assignmentGroup.I am using GORM criteria for this

this is `searchIncident.gsp`

```
 <tr class="prop">
       <td valign="top" class="name">
          <label for="assignmentGroup"><g:message code="incident.assignmentGroup.label" default="Assignment Group" /></label>
       </td>
       <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: incidentInstance, field: 'assignmentGroup', 'errors')}">
           <g:select  id="groupSelect" name="assignmentGroup.id" from="${app.Usergroup.list()}" optionKey="id"  value=""  />
       </td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="prop" >
     <td valign="top" class="name">
        <label for="status"><g:message code="incident.status.label" default="Status" /></label>
     </td>
     <td valign='top' class='value'>
       <g:select name='status'  from='${[""] + new Incident().constraints.status.inList}'>
       </g:select>
     </td> 
    </tr>
```

In my option tag i must select the first value empty(not null).

Comment: What do you mean by the first value empty?

Comment: '<td valign='top' class='value'>
                               <g:select name='servity'
                                from='${[""] + new Incident().constraints.servity.inList}'>
                               </g:select>
                             </td>  '

Comment: For `String status` ,we can write like tat rite in GSP to take first value empty.how can we get  `assignmentGroup` first value in same way.can you  guide me @ gotomanners please.

Answer (score 6):

If I've understood, you need to include the noSelection attribute, as in:

```
// use a no selection with a nullable Object property (use 'null' as key)
<g:select id="type" name='type.id' value="${person?.type?.id}"
    noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}"
    from='${PersonType.list()}'
   optionKey="id" optionValue="name"></g:select>
```

See the grails docs here for more: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html

Jim

Comment: For `String status` ,we can write like this  in GSP to take first value empty. `<td valign='top' class='value'> <g:select name='servity' from='${[""] + new Incident().constraints.servity.inList}'> </g:select> </td>`

Comment: How can we get `Usergroup assignment`,first value in same way.can you guide me @lo_toad

Comment: Still not sure what you mean? But if you want the default selected value to be a particular value you would specify it with `value='${userGroupInstance.id}'` or if you want a null selected fist value you would do something like `noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}"` the rest of the values will then come from the list that you provide to 'from'. It would be best* to decide what data and the order it goes into the list in the controller and then pass it to the if you want that displayed differently.